# How to move between markers on Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Does anybody know how to implement jumps between Markers after click on some anchors?

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="switching__list">
    <li><a href="" data-name="Black Sea">Black Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-name="Baltik Sea">Baltik Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-name="North Sea">North Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-name="Atlantic Ocean">Atlantic Ocean</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

and javascript

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptionsWatertemp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.533016, 34.557850),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    // Coordinates
    var blackSea = new google.maps.LatLng(43.533016, 34.557850);
    var balticSea = new google.maps.LatLng(57.415672, 19.927596);
    var northSea = new google.maps.LatLng(56.029392, 3.514022);
    var atlanticOcean = new google.maps.LatLng(35.391504, -10.178066);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptionsWatertemp);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: blackSea, map: map} );
    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: balticSea, map: map} );
    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: northSea, map: map} );
    marker4 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: atlanticOcean, map: map} );
}

initialize();
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/1dd3ss5p/)

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1dd3ss5p/2/)?

Comment: @geocodezip yes, sir! Exactly what I try to get!!! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:  make your map variable global (so it is available in HTML "click" events):

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
 var mapOptionsWatertemp = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.533016, 34.557850),
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
    // Coordinates
 var blackSea = new google.maps.LatLng(43.533016, 34.557850);
 var balticSea = new google.maps.LatLng(57.415672, 19.927596);
 var northSea = new google.maps.LatLng(56.029392, 3.514022);
 var atlanticOcean = new google.maps.LatLng(35.391504, -10.178066);

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptionsWatertemp);
    
    marker = new google.maps.Marker( {position: blackSea, map: map} );
    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: balticSea, map: map} );
    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: northSea, map: map} );
    marker4 = new google.maps.Marker( {position: atlanticOcean, map: map} );
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas 
{ 
height: 400px; 
width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<ul class="switching__list">
    <li><a href="javascript:map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());" data-name="Black Sea">Black Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());" data-name="Baltik Sea">Baltik Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());" data-name="North Sea">North Sea</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:map.setCenter(marker4.getPosition());" data-name="Atlantic Ocean">Atlantic Ocean</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1dd3ss5p/2/)